# LibGDX stretching screen onResume

Tags: java, android, libgdx, resume

When I start the app - everything's ok, the UI, player and tiles fits just fine. The problem appears when I try to resume app after, for example, locking and unlocking the screen.

Screen when **launching** the app: [image]

Screen after **resuming** it: [image]

## EDITED

---

**UiButton**

```
public class UiButton extends Sprite
{
    private boolean touched = false;

    public UiButton( Texture texture, float posX, float posY )
    {
        super( texture );
        setPosition( posX, posY );
    }

    @Override public void setSize( float toWidth, float toHeight )
    {
        super.setSize( toWidth, toHeight );
        setOriginCenter( );
    }

    public void setTouched( boolean touched ) { this.touched = touched; }
    public boolean getTouched( ) { return touched; }

    public boolean isTouched( float touchX, float touchY )
    {
        float xDiff = touchX - getX( ) - getWidth( ) / 2;
        float yDiff = touchY - getY( ) - getHeight( ) / 2;

        float distance = ( xDiff * xDiff ) + ( yDiff * yDiff );
        if( distance <= Calculation.square( getWidth( ) / 2 ) )
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

**GameScreen**

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen
{
    private final static int INITIAL_TILE_SIZE = 32;

    // Display variables
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private SpriteBatch        spriteBatch;
    private SpriteBatch        uiBatch;
    private Player             player;

    // Map variables
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;
    private TiledMap                   tiledMap;

    // User Interface variables
    private UiButton arrow_right;
    private UiButton arrow_left;
    private UiButton arrow_down;
    private UiButton arrow_up;
    private UiButton action;

    // FPS control variables
    int sleep_time     = 0;
    int frames_skipped = 0;

    @Override public void show( )
    {
        /** Setting InputProcessor **/
        InitializeInputProcessor( );

        /** Initializing Camera **/
        camera = new OrthographicCamera( );
        camera.setToOrtho( false );

        /** Initializing spriteBatch **/
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch( );
        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix( camera.combined );
        spriteBatch.maxSpritesInBatch = 5;

        /** Initializing uiBatch **/
        uiBatch = new SpriteBatch( );
        uiBatch.maxSpritesInBatch = 5;

        /** Creating map **/
        InitializeMap( );

        /** Creating Player **/
        player = new Player( Gdx.graphics.getWidth( ) / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight( ) / 2 );
        player.setSize( 32, 32 );

        /** Creating UI **/
        GenerateUI( Gdx.graphics.getHeight( ) / 60, Gdx.graphics.getHeight( ) / 5 );
    }

    public void doUpdating( )
    {
        /** Updating Player **/
        player.update( ( TiledMapTileLayer ) tiledMap.getLayers( ).get( 1 ) );

        /** Updating our Camera **/
        camera.position.set( player.getX( ), player.getY( ), 0 );
        camera.update( );
    }

    public void doRendering( )
    {
        /** Clearing the screen **/
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 1 );
        Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        mapRenderer.setView( camera );
        mapRenderer.render( );

        /** spriteBatch rendering **/
        spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix( camera.combined );
        spriteBatch.begin( );

        player.draw( spriteBatch );

        spriteBatch.end( );

        /** uiBatch rendering **/
        uiBatch.begin( );

        arrow_right.draw( uiBatch );
        arrow_left.draw( uiBatch );
        arrow_down.draw( uiBatch );
        arrow_up.draw( uiBatch );
        action.draw( uiBatch );

        uiBatch.end( );
    }


    @Override public void dispose( )
    {
        spriteBatch.dispose( );
        uiBatch.dispose( );
        tiledMap.dispose( );
        mapRenderer.dispose( );
    }

    private void InitializeMap( )
    {
        tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader( ).load( "maps/test.tmx" );
        mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer( tiledMap );
    }

    private void GenerateUI( float padding, float button_size )
    {
        arrow_right = new UiButton( new Texture( Gdx.files.internal( "ui/arrow_right_small.png" ) ), button_size * 1.4f + padding, button_size * 0.8f + padding );
        arrow_right.setSize( button_size, button_size );

        arrow_left = new UiButton( new Texture( Gdx.files.internal( "ui/arrow_left_small.png" ) ), padding, button_size * 0.8f + padding );
        arrow_left.setSize( button_size, button_size );

        arrow_up = new UiButton( new Texture( Gdx.files.internal( "ui/arrow_up_small.png" ) ), button_size * 0.8f, button_size * 1.6f + padding );
        arrow_up.setSize( button_size, button_size );

        arrow_down = new UiButton( new Texture( Gdx.files.internal( "ui/arrow_down_small.png" ) ), button_size * 0.8f, padding );
        arrow_down.setSize( button_size, button_size );

        action = new UiButton( new Texture( Gdx.files.internal( "ui/ic_target_small.png" ) ), Gdx.graphics.getWidth( ) - padding - button_size, padding + button_size );
        action.setSize( button_size * 1.5f, button_size * 1.5f );
    }

    @Override public void render( float delta )
    {
        final int MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;
        final int DESIRED_FPS     = 60;
        final int FRAME_PERIOD    = 1000 / DESIRED_FPS;

        if( sleep_time >= 0 || frames_skipped == MAX_FRAME_SKIPS )
        {
            long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis( );
            frames_skipped = 0;

            doUpdating( );
            doRendering( );

            long time_diff = System.currentTimeMillis( ) - start_time;
            sleep_time = ( int ) ( FRAME_PERIOD - time_diff );

            if( sleep_time > 0 )
            {
                try { Thread.sleep( sleep_time ); }
                catch( InterruptedException e )
                {
                    System.out.println( "InterruptedException while trying to execute Thread.sleep( " + sleep_time + " )\n" + e.getMessage( ) );
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            doUpdating( );

            sleep_time += FRAME_PERIOD;
            frames_skipped++;
        }
    }

    @Override public void resize( int width, int height )
    {
        camera.viewportHeight = 320;
        camera.viewportWidth = Math.round( 320 * Gdx.graphics.getWidth( ) / Gdx.graphics.getHeight( ) );
    }

    @Override public void resume( ) { }
    @Override public void pause( ) { }
    @Override public void hide( ) { }
}
```

Comment: one more question - what is your **android:screenOrientation=** value in AndroidManifest.xml file? (it is in android project)

Comment: I've set it to `sensorLandscape` so that user could rotate to the side he prefers

Comment: funny thing is that I don't observe this problem when trying your code on my phone... But it is definitely about viewport - try to add your camera viewport updateing code to the **resume()** method

Comment: Should I create **`new OrthograpicCamera`** for the UI ?

Comment: firstly just try to copy `camera.viewportHeight = 320;
        camera.viewportWidth = Math.round( 320 * Gdx.graphics.getWidth( ) / Gdx.graphics.getHeight( ) );` to the **resume()** method

Comment: nope, I've tried that before. I've even tried to create new OrthographicalCamera with that viewport and set projectionMatrix for the uiBatch as that camera - still not working...

Comment: It's still the problem. But the UI is strecthed only when you come back from locked screen...